# Data Visualization with 3 different data points

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Hope I can articulate what I am trying to do.
I have a file of crime data - what crime (arson, burglary, etc) and the time and date it occurred. I'm using Python, Dash and Plotly to make a dashboard to show different graphs for this data. The file is one row per crime.

I am currently adding column for each 'time bucket' the crime occurred. So a crime at 12:30 AM goes into the 12am-1am bucket. I add a column called 'Counter' with a value of 1. Then I do a count of Counter by each bucket by crime.

```
df4 = df3.groupby(['CrimeDesc' , 'TimeRange']).agg({      
                                     'Counter': "count" 
                                     })
```

I would like to make a graph like the one below - I made that in Excel. 
I tried to put two of the data points in the x or y axes, but that generates an error (KeyError: ('TimeRange', 'Counter')):

```
return {'data':[go.Bar(x=df5['CrimeDesc'],
                          y=df5['TimeRange','Counter'],
                        #  mode='markers',
                          marker={ #'size':15,
                                  'opacity':0.5,
                                  'line':{'width':0.5,'color':'green'}})
                          ],
                          'layout':go.Layout(title='Crime Stuff',
                          xaxis = {'title':'Crime Description'},
                          yaxis = {'title':'Number of Crimes'},
                          hovermode='closest'),}
```

[image]

Comment: That particular error is because you need to pass a list to retrieve multiple columns (`df5['TimeRange','Counter']` should be `df5[['TimeRange','Counter']]`). But I am not familiar with plotly's API so I don't know if it would solve your issues.

Comment: I tried that, got error message
TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable

Comment: I think I have it = I just made a list 
l = ['TimeRange','Counter']
x= l,
y=df5['Counter'}